# Changing pixel color value in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to change pixel color of an image in python. Except for the pixel value (255, 0, 0) red I need to change every pixel color value into black (0, 0, 0). I tried the following code but it doesn't helped.

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('A:\ex1.jpg')
for pixel in im.getdata():
    if pixel == (255,0,0):
        print "Red coloured pixel"
    else:
        pixel = [0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Watch out with backslashes in string literals. Use either raw strings `r'A:\ex1.jpg'` or escape them: `'A:\\ex1.jpg'`. Or just use slashes in path names: `'A:/ex1.jpg'`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See this wikibook: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library/Editing_Pixels

Modifying that code to fit your problem:

```
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map

for i in range(img.size[0]): # for every pixel:
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        if pixels[i,j] != (255, 0, 0):
            # change to black if not red
            pixels[i,j] = (0, 0 ,0)
```

Comment: Is not the OP need the other way around?  (Change non red pixels to black instead)?

Comment: Should it not be for i in range(pixels.size[0]): ?

Comment: The documentation describes that `load()` is slow: `Accessing individual pixels is fairly slow. If you are looping over all of the pixels in an image, there is likely a faster way using other parts of the Pillow API.` They don't specify anything beyond that, but [loxaxs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469395/1052284) is a fair guess.

Answer (score 31):

You could use [`img.putpixel`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putpixel):

```py
im.putpixel((x, y), (255, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the way I'd use PIL to do what you want:

```
from PIL import Image

imagePath = 'A:\ex1.jpg'
newImagePath = 'A:\ex2.jpg'
im = Image.open(imagePath)

def redOrBlack (im):
    newimdata = []
    redcolor = (255,0,0)
    blackcolor = (0,0,0)
    for color in im.getdata():
        if color == redcolor:
            newimdata.append( redcolor )
        else:
            newimdata.append( blackcolor )
    newim = Image.new(im.mode,im.size)
    newim.putdata(newimdata)
    return newim

redOrBlack(im).save(newImagePath)
```

Answer (score 6):

Taking the question to an extreme level, here's how to randomly change the channels in PIL (neglecting any 0, which I consider as background)

```
rr, gg, bb = in_img.split()
rr = rr.point(lambda p: 0 if p==0 else np.random.randint(256) )
gg = gg.point(lambda p: 0 if p==0 else np.random.randint(256) )
bb = bb.point(lambda p: 0 if p==0 else np.random.randint(256) )
out_img = Image.merge("RGB", (rr, gg, bb))
out_img.getextrema()
out_img.show()
```

Enjoy!