# Transparency not working consistently while saving GIF's in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transparency, gif

I am working on script that writes over images and makes the background transparent. Output is supposed to be in GIF format.

The script works but for certain images the transparency is not working as expected.

Here is the script

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

CANVAS_HEIGHT = 354
CANVAS_WIDTH = 344


def get_text_mask():
    font_style_path = 'Ultra-Regular.ttf'

    text_mask_base = Image.new('L', (CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT), 255)
    text_mask = text_mask_base.copy()
    text_mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_mask)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_style_path, 94)
    text_mask_width, text_mask_height = text_mask_draw.multiline_textsize("1000\nUsers",
                                                                          font=font)

    text_mask_draw.multiline_text(((CANVAS_WIDTH - text_mask_width) / 2,
                                   (CANVAS_HEIGHT - text_mask_height) / 2),
                                  "1000\nUsers",
                                  font=font,
                                  fill=0,
                                  align='center')

    return text_mask


def run():
    images = ['image1.png', 'image2.png']
    for index, original_image in enumerate(images):
        image = Image.open(original_image)
        blank_canvas = Image.new('RGBA', (CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT), (255, 255, 255, 0))
        text_mask = get_text_mask()
        final_canvas = blank_canvas.copy()
        for i in xrange(0, CANVAS_WIDTH, image.width):
            for j in xrange(0, CANVAS_HEIGHT, image.height):
                final_canvas.paste(image, (i, j))

        final_canvas.paste(text_mask, mask=text_mask)
        final_canvas.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
        final_canvas.save("output-{}.gif".format(index), format="GIF", transparency=0)

run()
```

[image]
image1.png

[image]
image2.png

And the font is here 
https://bipuljain.com/static/images/Ultra-Regular.ttf

And the output with issue. 
[image]

And output working fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your "original image" contains the same index-color that the GIFs use to signify "this pixel is transparent".

Gifs are "palette-based" - one index into this palette is designated as "this is transparent" (see f.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF)

So if you specify `pure black` or `pure white` as color-index that is transparent and your sourceimage already contains pixels with this exact color, they get to be transperent as well.

To avoid this, you could sample your source background-image and choose a "non-existent" color as transparency-color - this would never get to be in your resulting image.

You could also change your source images pixel values - check all pixel and change all "background-ones" a tiny fraction off so they do not get translucent.

Comment: @BipulJain this SO-post does pixel-replacement with PIL [Changing pixel color value in PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468530/changing-pixel-color-value-in-pil) - I havent done much in PIL - just happen to know a bit about graphic formats

Comment: Are you suggesting to changes all values that is white to transparent ? That is going to be expensive. Also i will be screwing the pixels inside the text area as well. Your sampling idea and using non-existent as transparency value would just fit in.

Comment: @BipulJain not sure on your performance concerns - you would have to change _all_ 255,255,255 pixels of your background to 254,254,254 (or smth) which would not make much impact on the resulting image when viewing it. Alternatively search all pixels of your image for a "not used" color and use that as background - whats more feasable you would have to evaluate. Maybe some PIL-Users will pipe in, just leave this answer as is and hope for someone to come up with some code would be my advice. There might be an ever better solution using PIL. Maybe something with paste options