# Putpixel function not generating all the pixels

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

My goal is to generate a color per pixel in order to fill up the whole canvas however the image generated always turns out black with only one of its pixels changed color, I can't seem to figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import random
from PIL import Image

canvas = Image.new("RGB", (300,300))

y = random.randint(1, canvas.width)
x = random.randint(1, canvas.width)

r = random.randint(0,255)
g = random.randint(0,255)
b = random.randint(0,255)

rgb = (r,g,b)

for i in range(canvas.width): 
    canvas.putpixel((x,y), (rgb))

canvas.save("test.png", "PNG")

print("Image saved successfully.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should try and avoid using `for` loops in any Python image processing - they are slow and error-prone.

The easiest and fastest way to make a random image is using vectorised Numpy functions like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Create Numpy array 300x300x3 of random uint8
data = np.random.randint(0, 256, (300,300,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Make into PIL Image
im = Image.fromarray(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are not iterating over every pixel. I've modified your code to iterate over every pixel, check whether or not it is black `(0,0,0)`, then place a pixel on that iteration with your randomly-generated `rgb` value. Then, I regenerate 3 new random numbers and place them back into the `rgb` tuple causing the next pixel in the loop to have a different `rgb` value.

The `x` and `y` definitions are redundant, as you want a random color for every pixel but do not want random pixels, so I have removed them. I added a declaration, `pixels = canvas.load()` which allocates memory for the pixels so you can iterate over them and change each individual color. I heavily relied on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468530/changing-pixel-color-value-in-pil) similar stackoverflow question, if you want further information. Here is my code:

```
canvas = Image.new("RGB", (300,300))
pixels = canvas.load()

width, height = canvas.size

for i in range(width): 
    for j in range(height):
        if pixels[i,j] == (0,0,0):
            r = random.randint(0,255)
            g = random.randint(0,255)
            b = random.randint(0,255)
            rgb = (r,g,b)
            canvas.putpixel((i,j), (rgb))
            
canvas.save("test.png", "PNG")

print("Image saved successfully.")
```

Here is the output produced:

[image]

Comment: You're right, I've removed those assignments. My apologies, as this is my first time working with PIL.