# How to deliberately create corrupt image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have some image files, i want generate some test image files base on these files for AI program recognization.
Now i am wondering is there any way i can use python3 `PIL` module or other module that can process image to create some `corrupted` image for validation purpose?

Corrupted image:
open image failed, or add hollow or black pixel in origin image
Base code:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('test.jpg')
w, h = im.size
# corrupted image TODO

im.save('thumbnail.jpg', 'jpeg')
```

Comment: What do you mean by `corrupted` image, what kind of corruption?

Comment: Such like, run `im.verify()` failed, or create some hole black pixel in origin images

Comment: You could use a hex editor to change some bytes. Or use `dd` to chop some bytes off the end of a file.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, but it's impossible to guess what you really want without a clear problem statement.

Comment: I want to find a way to edit image base on origin one, and do some "nasty" movement. like randomly delete some pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove some pixels (make them black) by getting the pixels in the image with `im.load()` and assigning a black value `(0, 0, 0)` to them in random locations. (Idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36468996/8873143))

Something like this:

```py
from PIL import Image
import random

im = Image.open('test.jpg')
w, h = im.size

pixels = im.load()

# Curruption by adding black pixels (make it grainy):
for _ in range(10000):
    pixels[random.randint(0, w - 1), random.randint(0, h - 1)] = (0, 0, 0)

im.save('thumbnail.jpg', 'jpeg')
```

Which will give some something like this as an output:

[image: Picture with black dots]